# Select all after comma with comma included

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

Been checking all the regex testers and documentation, and the best outcome I could get was select all without the comma.

String example

ex1,ex2,ex3,ex4,ex5,ex6

Regular expression used

(,(.+))

Output

ex2,ex3,ex4,ex5,ex6

How do I select the comma before ex2

Comment: Something wrong with the obvious `(,.+)`? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: for some reason it produces different results on my end, on regex101 it appears as green the one you've mentioned, mine appears as orange. So whenever i try to insert in the tool,  it doesn't work

Comment: Please include some code what you are doing.

Comment: I don't directly code it, I'm inserting on a tool, where it requests the regular expression, however comparing it on regex101, is what I mention. with the suggested it doesn't even consider it , with mine it's just missing removing that first comma

Comment: This looks like a non-standard regex, or at least the delimiters look non-standard. If your `(,(.+))` does not include the comma in the capture group try this: `((,.+))`

Answer (score 0):

```
,.*$
```

The regex above first searches for a comma, then any character afterwards. The * mark makes the previous search criteria run until finished

Comment: On the tool I'm using, (,.+) and (,.*$) don't work.

Comment: where are you using it? I tried both and they work on regex101.com

Comment: It's an indexation tool for content, I'm creating a mapper to take out some of the keywording that comes with the process.
as mentioned above, they work similarly however on regex101 the one above presented appears as group1 ( green ),the one I've mentioned appears as group 2 orange, it's the only difference i see